# Saving subclass model with custom training

Tags: tensorflow, nlp

I want to save custom model, build using tensorflow subclass. It is trained using custom training. (Not .fit() or .compile() method).

For example this tutorials -
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/nmt_with_attention
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/image_captioning

I didn't find the documentation for saving such models so as to convert it to tensorflow lite format and use it on android/ ios devices.

Thank you in advance.

I have searched a lot. please help me if you know the answer.

Comment: Create model and train model using custom training then save model as model.save('sample_model'). For more details on the library find [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load#savedmodel_format). Thanks!